# rosserial_arduino with arduino IDE 0022

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a arduIMU v3 and strictly have to use arduino IDE 0023 and below.

When I tried to compile the rosserial_arduino example for HelloWorld using the Arduino IDE 0022, the following error occur:

In file included from /home/user/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:39:0,
from HelloWorld.cpp:6:
/home/user/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:41:38: fatal error: Wprogram.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I have check that Wprogram.h is in my /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino

I am not sure whats the problem, will appreciate the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38353/rosserial_arduino-with-arduino-ide-0022/) by [halfstopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2417/halfstopper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just realize is the cap case different.

For those using Arduino IDE 0023 and below please take note:

Edit the ArduinoHardware.h header file supplied with the ros_lib,
change
#include "Wprogram.h"
to
#include "WProgram.h"

---

Originally posted by [halfstopper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2417/halfstopper/) with karma: 26 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0